# Whats the difference between initializing a variable within a class VS without??? - swift

Tags: swift, class, initialization

Here's my problem, I have a variable that I initialize once so that I don't have to call the database every time I want to use that variable. How should I structure it? Example 1 or 2? What's the difference between putting functions and variables inside a class vs without a class?

example 1 (no class):

```
import UIKit

var username = "" 

func callToDatbase () {
// I run my code to set the username value equal to stored username value within the database
//Ex: username = database.username
}



---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Then when I want to call it in another view controller I would just say:
usernameLabel.text = username
```

Example 2 (with class):

```
import UIKit

class Initializers {

var username = ""

  func callToDatbase () {
    // I run my code to set the username value equal to stored username value within the database
    //Ex: self.username = database.username
  }

}


---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Then when I want to call it in another view controller I would just say:
usernameLabel.text = Initializers().username
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialise a variable outside of the class it is store in the global scope. The scope in swift is defined by the curly brackets, so you can think about the outside of the class as the whole project surrounded by the curly brackets. When you define the variable inside of the class it is only going to be available from that class when you instantiate it as an object. You might want to read about inheritance to find out what else you can do with variables in classes.

**TLDR**: Variable outside will be available to the whole code, whereas the one inside the class will only be available from within the class or by accessing it as a property from instantiated object.

Example code:

```swift
class Example {
    var name = "Antoni"
}

print(name) // Will throw error

let example = Example() // Create an instance of the class
print(example.name) // Prints as expected
```

It is preferred to put variables in some sort of instantiable/destructible structure like a class to help swift with memory management. The variables defined globally will not be removed from memory until the program exits. And if you need to store static variables use struct instead.

Comment: TBH Memory concerns are the least of the worries about global variables. The huge technical complexity they impose would be a way more expensive problem to fix.

Comment: depends on how much you initialise globally

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica define "technical complexity"

Comment: Shared mutable state is always a liability when it comes to multithreading, and there's nothing "more shared" than "accessible everywhere" global variables. Also, the implicit dependencies that prevent you from reusing code, making isolated tests, and make reasoning about code more difficult (because nothing can be thought about in isolation)